# comparison of performance difference between RSA, ManagedRijndael & Managed AES in C#

Tags: performance, algorithm, encryption, analysis

I am comparing these 3 algorithms, i feel that the RSA takes more time, but i am not able to conclude which is best.

The following are the performance profiler results taken for the 3 methods using the code given by microsoft 
[image: Managed Rijandel Method]

[image: Managed AES Method]

[image: RSA Method]

All the input strings are `Here is some data to encrypt!`.

Can any one suggest me, i assert that RSA has performance penalty due to the import parameters method and i think of using the ManagedRijandel Method.

I am using this for a place where a normal encryption [not very strong and slow] is needed but it should be performant.

Kindly give me analysis details from your perspective + suggestions.

Note: 
1. it is not better to compare symmetric and asymmetric.. but i need some strong analysis.

2. Also, my memory profiling shows less memory usage with RSA.
3. Framework : .Net Framework V4 with C# & VS2010
   Kindly suggest.

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Comment: This question is about the choice of algorithms based on performance, anyways measuring algorithm performance using profilers do need code and i've done it using C#. I need opinion from experts, this forum does this better than any.

Comment: Comparing RSA to AES is like comparing apples to oranges. Each cipher has a completely different goal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RSA will be slower than a symmetric cypher like Rijndael or AES.  The usual method is to use RSA to encrypt a small key (128 or 256 bits) to send to the destination.  The key is then used to encrypt a much larger data file, using AES or Rijndael, which the destination now has the correct key to decrypt at their end.

In short, use RSA for small pieces of data and AES/Rijndael for large pieces of data.

Comment: any analysis comments on the results above?